# getting Value of type 'Set' has no member 'compactMap' FBAcessToken

Tags: ios, swift

```
var grantedSwiftPermissions: Set? { return (permissions?.compactMap { $0 as? String }.map { Permission(name: $0) }).map(Set.init) }
```

What is wrong in above code, Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

This is probably **due to** your **Xcode version**,

Currently you are using **xCode version <= 9.2** which support **flatMap**.

In FBCorekit library they included **compactMap**, which was introduced in xCode v 9.3.
So update your Xcode or use old library of Facebook.

Hope this will work.

If I am wrong or can be correct more than please welcome.